# Javascript search and replace need to incorporate more

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my search and replace I came up with. How can I incorporate a comment or alert to describe the pattern and a functional box for the input?  Any advice is appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Search & Replace</title>
</head>
<body>

<script language="javascript">

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class StringReplace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "The quick blue bird flies over the brown baseball   field.";
        String find = "blue";
        String replace = "brown";

        //
        // Compiles the given regular expression into a pattern
       //
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(find);

       //
       // Creates a matcher that will match the given input against the pattern
       //
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);

        //
        // Replaces every subsequence of the input sequence that matches the
        // pattern with the given replacement string
        //
        String output = matcher.replaceAll(replace);

        System.out.println("Source = " + source);
          System.out.println("Output = " + output);
    }
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Java" is to "JavaScript" as "Ham" is to "Hamster".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid javascript, the console will throw an error if you try and load this page on the import:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

It appears to be a Java class, which won't run in the browser, unless you are using a technology like jsp.

There are a few libraries which already will do string stuff like this.  Try stringjs for example: http://stringjs.com/.  However, if you want to run this over a whole page, you'll need to parse the DOM which is more complicated (doing this for a string is much easier).

For using an input, you should look into html deeper.  There are a number of textbox and textfield options, which you can bind to javascript.